# Visual FoxPro Report Problems - Summary Band

Tags: foxpro

I have a a picture file that needs to go in the Summary Band of a report. However, depending on how much data is on a page, the picture will sometimes span two pages. Is there any way to prevent pictures from spanning pages and force a page break to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, is the image always the same size, or is it dynamically generated.  If its static, such as a company logo, obviously, I would put it in the page footer and have a conditional "PRINT WHEN EOF()".  Page footers should always be printed in their entirety, hence a footer (intention is constant size at every page).  This way, your image wont show on every prior page, only the last one after the last detail has been generated.

Comment: I have items in the footer already. Are you suggesting I move this item into the footer and put "EOF()" in the "Print only when expression is true" box?